# How to resolve access denied error in Multi stage Docker file for nextjs with file upload

Tags: docker, next.js, dockerfile, docker-swarm

I want to containerize a nextjs project using docker . I am  trying to upload some text files in container at absolute path `/data/service` folder of container . But I am getting access denied error from nextjs api . when I run this project locally (without docker) I can save the file on my windows os .
Here is the docker file I am using

```
# Install dependencies only when needed
FROM node:14-alpine AS deps
# Check https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/tree/b4117f9333da4138b03a546ec926ef50a31506c3#nodealpine to understand why
# libc6-compat might be needed.
RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json yarn.lock ./
RUN yarn install --frozen-lockfile

# Rebuild the source code only when needed
FROM node:14-alpine AS builder

ARG BUILD_BUILDNUMBER
ENV BUILD_BUILDNUMBER=${BUILD_BUILDNUMBER:-undefined}

WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
COPY --from=deps /app/node_modules ./node_modules
RUN yarn build

# Production image, copy all the files and run next
FROM node:14-alpine AS runner

ARG BUILD_BUILDNUMBER
ENV BUILD_BUILDNUMBER=${BUILD_BUILDNUMBER:-undefined}

WORKDIR /app

ENV NODE_ENV production

RUN addgroup -g 1001 -S nodejs
RUN adduser -S nextjs -u 1001

# You only need to copy next.config.js if you are NOT using the default configuration
COPY --from=builder /app/next.config.js ./

# Allow react-env access to write to public directory 
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/public ./public
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next ./.next
COPY --from=builder /app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY --from=builder /app/package.json ./package.json

USER nextjs

EXPOSE 3000

# Next.js collects completely anonymous telemetry data about general usage.
# Learn more here: https://nextjs.org/telemetry
# Uncomment the following line in case you want to disable telemetry.
ENV NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED 1

CMD ["yarn", "start"]
```

I tried adding `RUN mkdir -p /data/offers` . but i am still getting same error.
I try to run the code with volume mounted

```
docker run -p 3000:3000 -v data/service:data/service imagename
```

then my application gives me error
**permission denied.**

but if run

```
docker run -p 3000:3000
```

I am able to load files into container system.

Comment: What permissions does the `/data/service` folder have inside the docker container? You can find out like this `docker exec -it <id> ls -l /data`.

Comment: I don't see that directory mentioned in the Dockerfile at all.  You need to make sure to `chown` it to the user that's running the container as well.  (You do not need to `chown` your application code.)  If it's a mounted volume, you may need to specify an alternate user that has write permissions when you run the container.

Comment: I tried 
```RUN mkdir -p /data/service&& chown nextjs:nodejs /data/service```
but still getting permission error when using mounted volumes . I have update question for run command.